# How to create a unique key on a date chained table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, unique-constraint

I have two tables : `employee` and a child table `employeeVacation`.

**employee**

```
id
employeeName
```

**employeeVacation**

```
employeeId
vacationStartDate
vacationEndDate
```

`employee` holds a list of employees and has a unique key on the `employeeName` column. 
`employeeVacation` holds details of each employee's vacation dates. It has a foregin key on `employeeId` to the `employee.id` column. There can be multiple rows per `employeeId` in this table. It has no unique key.

Is there a better way to structure these two tables such that a unique key can be created on the `employeeVacation` table (or it's equivalent)? I am looking for unique key or structural change that prevents date overlaps.

Example of such an overlap that I want to avoid:

**Row 1**

```
employeeId =1
startDate = 2015-01-01
endDate = 2015-02-15
```

**Row 2**

```
employeeId =1
startDate = 2015-02-10
endDate = 2015-02-20
```

Best I can come up with is a unique key on `employeeId` & `startDate`.

Been scratching my head for a few years and still can't think of one so would appreciate any help!

Comment: IMO, this is business logic that should be handled either by the front-end or by the code inserting it into the database (if you use SQL for final validation). AFAIK a unique key cannot check for overlapping data, just uniqueness, if you want to enforce this rule on the table, you might also look at triggers for insert and update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve this with the data model given plus some unique constraint, as the ranges *are* unique, but that doesn't say anything about whether they overlap or not.

There are two solutions possible:

1. Instead of a unique constraint, you'd write a BEFORE INSERT trigger (and possibly a before update trigger, too) that uses a query to check whether an overlapping record exists in order to raise an exception in case. It depends on the dbms whether it supports such feature.
2. You can make your model more complicated, such that it deals with days. Then "unique" *does* mean "not overlapping".

Primary keys bold:

- employee (**empno**, name)
- vacation (**empno, vacationno**, status)
- vacationday (**empno, vacationno, day**)

You may be able to do without the connecting vacation table:

- employee (**empno**, name)
- vacationday (**empno, day**)

Or with an ID based database (additional unique keys italic):

- employee (**id_employee**, *empno*, name)
- vacationday (**id_vacationday**, *day, id_employee*)

With an ID based database *and* the convenient vacation table, you might have to introduce redundancy though, if you want the dbms to guarantee consistency (which is often the case with ID based systems):

- employee (**id_employee**, *empno*, name)
- vacation (**id_vacation**, id_employee, status)
- vacationday (**id_vacationday**, id_vacation, *day, id_employee*)

You see, you'd still need id_employee in vacationday here in spite of it being implicitly stated by the reference to vacation. However, some dbms allow you to have a unique constraint on a view, so you could join vacation and vacationday and have a unique constraint on (vacationday.day, vacation.id_employee), so you'd get off without the redundancy problem.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation of the options Thorsten. Reckon this is the best answer!